# Handlebar Object values cant by accessed by 'this' keyword

Tags: node.js, express-handlebars, handlebarshelper

I was rendering an array on a hbs template where I couldn't render the object value using 'this' keyword . also tried without 'this' but not worked. Please check the image for more clarification.

```html
{{#each products }}
<div class="row">
    {{#each this }}
    {{!-- {{ printing oject  }} --}}

    <p>{{this}}</p>

    {{!-- {{ actual-render  }} --}}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="" alt="..." class="image-responsive">
            <div class="caption">
                <h3>{{ this.title }}</h3>
                <p class="description">{{ this.description }}</p>
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <div class="price float-left">{{ this.price }}$</div>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-success float-right" role="button">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{/each }}
</div>
{{/each }}
```

[image: Code]

[image: output]

Comment: What is your second iteration inside your products? You can simply use in your first iteration: `{{title}}` without this keyword, just remove the second - as I see product is already an object

Comment: @iamzozo i tried this also but not worked

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed by allowing prototype-access to hbs

I followed this on app.js

step 1

```
npm install @handlebars/allow-prototype-access
```

step 2  add these lines at beginning of app.js

```
 const Handlebars = require('handlebars')
 const {allowInsecurePrototypeAccess} = require('@handlebars/allow-prototype-access')
```

step 3. change the line

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: 'main',  
  extname: 'hbs',
});
```

to

```
const hbs = exphbs.create({
  defaultLayout: 'main', 
  extname: 'hbs',
  handlebars: allowInsecurePrototypeAccess(Handlebars)
});
```